# How to create an complex128 tensor using tf.range

Tags: tensorflow

The following lines work:

```
t1 = tf.constant([-2.0, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 2.0], dtype=tf.complex128)
tf.sqrt(t1)
print(t1)
```

Now if I use

```
t1 = tf.range(-2.0, 3.0, 1, dtype=tf.complex128)
tf.sqrt(t1)
print(t1)
```

I get the usual error :

> Node:{{node Range}} All kernels registered for op Range :
>   device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_FLOAT]   device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_DOUBLE]
>   device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_INT32]   device='CPU'; Tidx in [DT_INT64]
>   device='GPU'; Tidx in [DT_FLOAT]   device='GPU'; Tidx in [DT_DOUBLE]
>   device='GPU'; Tidx in [DT_INT32]   device='GPU'; Tidx in [DT_INT64]
>   device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; Tidx in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32,
>   DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]   device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; Tidx in
>   [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]
>   device='XLA_CPU'; Tidx in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_INT64,
>   DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]   device='XLA_GPU'; Tidx in [DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF]  [Op:Range]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this error, it is saying that input to the `tf.range` should be one of `double`, `float`, `int` are registered for `op Range on device: CPU and GPU`. But your input is `complex128`, hence it return `NotFoundError`.

If we haven't specified any `dtype` (i.e. dtype is None), it inferred `dtype` from `dtype_hierarchy: dtypes.int32, dtypes.int64, dtypes.float32, dtypes.float64` as per as per `arg.dtype`.

Workaround to create `complex128` tensor using `tf.range` is as below with the help of `tf.cast`

```
t1 = tf.range(-2.0, 3.0, 1)
# casts tensor to a complex128 dtype.
t2 = tf.cast(t1, dtype=tf.complex128)
# apply sqrt function
tf.sqrt(t2)
# print output
print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([-2. -1.  0.  1.  2.], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-2.+0.j -1.+0.j  0.+0.j  1.+0.j  2.+0.j], shape=(5,), dtype=complex128)
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I did. I was wondering why tf.range does not have a complex node. thanks

Comment: @CrazyBrazilian, Can you please accept answer, if it answers your question. Thanks !